# Is it possible to sync mobile local data with one central dynamodb using cognito-sync?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I'm new to the AWS services and would like to understand if it is possible to use dynamodb and cognito sync in this specific scenario:

- publish data from a company office to few tables on one central dynamodb
- use cognito sync in a mobile app to periodically get those tables copied to storage local to the mobile device (unidirectional sync from central dynamodb to the remote mobile devices)

it is my understanding that cognito sync is normally used to sync profile data of the user, but i would like to understand if it is possible to use it in this different way (one dynamodb repository for all the authorized mobile users).

Thank you,
Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Amazon Cognito Sync provides its own per-identity storage (ie: storage not shared between your app users) but if you want to have a shared DynamoDB database, you can still use Amazon Cognito Identity with a role that gives read access to those tables to your users.

Albert

Comment: I understand that giving read access with a role is a needed step, but the main point for me is knowing if Cognito's sync functionality could be used with dynamodb tables

Comment: No, you can only use Amazon Cognito Sync with its own storage system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [AWS Cognito Sync Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/cognito-events/) to trigger a AWS Lambda. Then use the Cognito Sync data passed to event, to update the AWS Dynamodb table.